# exception on jsp page with resultSet

Tags: java, jsp, resultset

I am trying to check if a user has voted or not with this method below. I used the same method as login and login works perfectly. An error is occuring in the ResultSet execute query part. This is to check if the user already voted or not.

```
public boolean checkVote(int userId) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{        
    String query = "SELECT * FROM polls WHERE User='"+ userId +"''";        
    connect();        
    PreparedStatement ps = (PreparedStatement) dbConnection.prepareStatement(query);
    ResultSet results = (ResultSet)ps.executeQuery();

    while(results.next())
    {
         return true;
    }
    disconnect();
    return false;

}
```

Stack Trace:

```
     org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page     /    Gadgets.jsp at line 40

 37:                 <%db.DBConnection db = new  db.DBConnection(); 
 38:                 ArrayList<Product> myProducts =db.getAllProducts();
 39:                 User u = db.getUser(session.getAttribute("Username").toString());
 40:                 boolean checkVote = db.checkVote(u.getId());
 41:                 if(checkVote == true)
 42:                                        { %>
 43:                                          <form id="Gadgets" action="Gadgets.jsp"      method="post">
```

Comment: your stacktrace does not show the exception

Comment: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /Gadgets.jsp at line 40

37:                 <%db.DBConnection db = new  db.DBConnection(); 
38:                 ArrayList<Product> myProducts =db.getAllProducts();
39:                 User u = db.getUser(session.getAttribute("Username").toString());
40:                 boolean checkVote = db.checkVote(u.getId());
41:                 if(checkVote == true)
42:                                        { %>
43:                                          <form id="Gadgets" action="Gadgets.jsp" method="post">

Comment: are you using exactly the same code as you paste here? because i think in your sql code is a little error at the end `+ userId + "''"` - there are two `'` also in your code or this is just a mistake in your question only? If your code looks the same as here it's possible that there are exception under `JasperException`, some kind of `SQLException` and `JasperException` is just an effect of `SQLException`. Can it be true?

Comment: As a side note: [using scriplets in JSP is highly discouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3180202/814702)

Answer (score 0):

Not about your exception, but there's a comment on your code. Since you're not using statement parameters (passed through `?`) you don't need `PreparedStatement`, you can use simple `Statement` and get it through `connection.createStatement`. Or better approach is to keep using `PreparedStatement` and pass `userId` through parameter.

More on this [here](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t124880-createstatement-vs-preparestatement.html)

Now about your exception. Seems that `checkVote` method is your servlet method, and not method of your `db` object. But you're trying to call `db's` `checkVote`. This is a reason of `JasperException`.

Comment: checkVote method is in the same class DBConnection class

Comment: then please onclude class bounds into your sources, coz that's not obvious what is checkVote

Comment: Add full class definition, not the only method, coz it's not clear what is checkVote method.